# Html Pug: Is this Right or wrong?

Tags: html, web, pug

i am trying to learn "pug' i want to  convert this HTML to pug

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a class="button" href="#">Go to homepage</a>
</div>
```

my pug version

```
.buttons 
a.button(class={active: currentUrl === '#'} href='#') Go to homepage
```

**is correct ?**

Comment: I've removed the javadoc tag in your question. If it happened to be a relevant one you can edit the question and add it again, but please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct version for your html code in pug is

```
.buttons
    a.button(href='#') Go to homepage
```

Keep indentation in mind while writing equivalent pug. Follow the links below

[More about pug here](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

[Online HTML to Pug converter](http://html2jade.org/)